# Convert a nested list in dendrogram/tree with R

Tags: r, list, tree, nested-lists

is it possible to convert a heterogeneous nested list (which contains character vectors, other lists, and lists of lists) into a dendrogram or a tree object? the idea would be that, from an hypothetical point of origin, each nested levels add a new layer of branches.

An example for such a list can be this:

```
list(c("tom", "bob", "red"), c("jin", "tonic"), list(c("megan", "tina"), "carl"), "tim", list(c("chris", list(c("stella", "mia", "charly"))), "jack"))
```

And the desired output (e.g. in newick format) should look like this:

```
plot(read.tree(text = "((tom,bob,red),(jin,tonic),((megan,tina),carl),tim,((chris,(stella,mia,charly)),jack));"))
```

Thanks a lot,

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the night I found a bit of inspiration...

I made this workaround to get my nested list to a newick format tree:

```
x <- list(c("tom", "bob", "red"), c("jin", "tonic"), list(c("megan", "tina"), "carl"), "tim", list(c("chris", list(c("stella", "mia", "charly"))), "jack"))

# flatten list
x2 <- paste0(lapply(x, function(y) paste0("(", paste0(y, collapse = ","), ")")), collapse = ",")

# remove unwanted characters
x2 <- gsub('\"|c|list| ', "", x2)
x2 <- paste0("(", x2, ");")

# remove brackets from single term list object
library(stringr)
x3 <- str_replace_all(x2, "\\([a-z]*\\)", function(x) gsub("^\\(|\\)$", "", x))

# plot
library(ape)
plot(read.tree(text = x3))
```